# Flexbox overflowing body by exact width of scrollbar

Tags: html, css, wordpress, flexbox

I have a problem that I'm absolutely banging my head over. Can't figure it out for the life of me..

I'm building a custom WP theme, and having some issues with the flexbox elements overflowing the width of the body, and creating a horizontal scroll. (see attached image)

[image]

It is only the flexbox images that are overflowing the container. I verified this by running a small piece of code to return the items wider than the viewport.

My research shows that this is because the width of the viewport is calculated before the scrollbar, and that's what I imagine to be causing these issues.

I can confirm that this issue doesn't occur on pages without scrollbars.

I tried hiding the x overflow, but as you might guess it doesn't make things properly centered.

Here are some blocks of code from the affected elements:

```
header#header {
    width: 100vw;
    height: calc(100vh - 98px);
    text-align: center;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    -webkit-animation: bgcolor 20s infinite;
    animation: bgcolor 10s infinite;
    -webkit-animation-direction: alternate;
    animation-direction: alternate;
}
```

```
.menu {
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    width: 100vw;
    background-color: white;
    justify-content: space-between;
    padding: 25px;
    font-size: 3em;
}
```

```
.widget_mc4wp_form_widget {
    width: 100vw;
    padding: 25px;
    border-top: 5px dashed blue;
    border-bottom: 5px dashed blue;
}
```

```
div#copyright {
    display: flex;
    text-align: center;
    flex-direction: column;
}
```

I'm using firefox 74.0, same issue happens in chrome and safari.

If you need more details I can post a link to the full CSS file and the live site but that might be a bit out of scope.

Thank you!!

Comment: What is the wrapper of header?  post the HTML blocks as they appear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, what seemed to fix it was replacing vw with % in any css rules using 100vw.

(eg, `width: 100%` vs `width: 100vw`).

I guess that vw is calculated before the width of the body was, which was causing these elements to overflow out of the body.

I confirmed this by checking the width of the elements set to 100vw (1920px), vs the elements that were calculated using 100% (1905px). The scrollbar is exactly 15px wide in Firefox.